# Dart Flutter Plugin project :firebase_core_web and :firebase_auth_webnot found Error

Tags: android, firebase, flutter

When I run my codes I get these errors:

```
Launching lib\main.dart on Android SDK built for x86 in debug mode...
Plugin project :firebase_core_web not found. Please update settings.gradle.
Plugin project :firebase_auth_web not found. Please update settings.gradle.

FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

* Where:
Script 'C:\src\flutter\packages\flutter_tools\gradle\flutter.gradle' line: 421

* What went wrong:
A problem occurred evaluating root project 'android'.
> A problem occurred configuring project ':app'.
   > Cannot invoke method afterEvaluate() on null object
* Try:
Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace. Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output. Run with --scan to get full insights.
* Get more help at https://help.gradle.org
BU�LD FAILED in 1s
Exception: Gradle task assembleDebug failed with exit code 1
Exited (sigterm)
```

---

`auth.dart:`

```
import 'package:firebase_auth/firebase_auth.dart';
import 'package:google_sign_in/google_sign_in.dart';

final FirebaseAuth _auth = FirebaseAuth.instance;
final GoogleSignIn googleSignIn = GoogleSignIn();

Future<String> signInWithGoogle() async {
  final GoogleSignInAccount? googleSignInAccount = await googleSignIn.signIn();
  final GoogleSignInAuthentication googleSignInAuthentication =
      await googleSignInAccount!.authentication;
  final AuthCredential credential = GoogleAuthProvider.getCredential(
    accessToken: googleSignInAuthentication.accessToken,
    idToken: googleSignInAuthentication.idToken,
  );

  final AuthResult authResult = await _auth.signInWithCredential(credential);
  final FirebaseUser user = authResult.user;
  assert(!user.isAnonymous);
  assert(await user.getIdToken() != null);
  final FirebaseUser currentUser = await _auth.currentUser();
  assert(user.uid == currentUser.uid);
  return 'signInWithGoogle succeeded: $user';
}

void signOutGoogle() async{
  await googleSignIn.signOut();
}
```

---

`android/build.gradle:`

```
buildscript {
    ext.kotlin_version = '1.5.31'
    repositories {
        google()
        mavenCentral()
    }

    dependencies {
        classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:4.1.0'
        classpath "org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-gradle-plugin:$kotlin_version"
        classpath 'com.google.gms:google-services:4.3.10'
    }
}

allprojects {
    repositories {
        google()
        mavenCentral()
    }
}

rootProject.buildDir = '../build'
subprojects {
    project.buildDir = "${rootProject.buildDir}/${project.name}"
}
subprojects {
    project.evaluationDependsOn(':app')
}

task clean(type: Delete) {
    delete rootProject.buildDir
}
```

---

`android/app/build.gradle:`

```
def localProperties = new Properties()
def localPropertiesFile = rootProject.file('local.properties')
if (localPropertiesFile.exists()) {
    localPropertiesFile.withReader('UTF-8') { reader ->
        localProperties.load(reader)
    }
}

def flutterRoot = localProperties.getProperty('flutter.sdk')
if (flutterRoot == null) {
    throw new GradleException("Flutter SDK not found. Define location with flutter.sdk in the local.properties file.")
}

def flutterVersionCode = localProperties.getProperty('flutter.versionCode')
if (flutterVersionCode == null) {
    flutterVersionCode = '1'
}

def flutterVersionName = localProperties.getProperty('flutter.versionName')
if (flutterVersionName == null) {
    flutterVersionName = '1.0'
}

apply plugin: 'com.android.application'
apply plugin: 'com.google.gms.google-services'
apply plugin: 'kotlin-android'
apply from: "$flutterRoot/packages/flutter_tools/gradle/flutter.gradle"

android {
    compileSdkVersion flutter.compileSdkVersion

    compileOptions {
        sourceCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_1_8
        targetCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_1_8
    }

    kotlinOptions {
        jvmTarget = '1.8'
    }

    sourceSets {
        main.java.srcDirs += 'src/main/kotlin'
    }

    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "com.example.simto_todolist"
        minSdkVersion 21
        targetSdkVersion flutter.targetSdkVersion
        versionCode flutterVersionCode.toInteger()
        versionName flutterVersionName
    }

    buildTypes {
        release {
            signingConfig signingConfigs.debug
        }
    }
}

flutter {
    source '../..'
}

dependencies {
    implementation "org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-stdlib-jdk7:$kotlin_version"
    implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-analytics-ktx'
    implementation platform('com.google.firebase:firebase-bom:29.2.1')
}
```

---

I'm trying to make Auth systems with Firebase. I'm setting up login option with Google. I did exactly what was in the guide post, but I'm getting this error. Required codes etc. I added it as in the guide. `minSdkVersion` was normally 16, I searched the internet and found that it should be changed to 21 in a solution. I changed it but still the same.

Why am I having this problem? How can i solve it. Thanks in advance for the help.

---

After doing what Dhruvi Pandya said I got this error:

```
Launching lib\main.dart on Android SDK built for x86 in debug mode...

FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

* Where:
Build file 'C:\Users\emiry\Desktop\Simto-To-Do-List\simto_todolist\android\build.gradle' line: 27

* What went wrong:
A problem occurred evaluating root project 'android'.
> Project with path ':app' could not be found in project ':firebase_auth'.
* Try:
Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace. Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output. Run with --scan to get full insights.

* Get more help at https://help.gradle.org

BU�LD FAILED in 1s
Exception: Gradle task assembleDebug failed with exit code 1
Exited (sigterm)
```

`android/build.gradle:`

```
buildscript {
    ext.kotlin_version = '1.5.0'
    repositories {
        google()
        mavenCentral()
    }

    dependencies {
        classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:4.1.0'
        classpath "org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-gradle-plugin:$kotlin_version"
        classpath 'com.google.gms:google-services:4.3.10'
    }
}

allprojects {
    repositories {
        google()
        mavenCentral()
    }
}

rootProject.buildDir = '../build'
subprojects {
    project.buildDir = "${rootProject.buildDir}/${project.name}"
}
subprojects {
    project.evaluationDependsOn(':app')
}

task clean(type: Delete) {
    delete rootProject.buildDir
}
```

---

2nd error I get:

```
The plugin `firebase_auth` uses a deprecated version of the Android embedding.
To avoid unexpected runtime failures, or future build failures, try to see if this plugin supports the Android V2 embedding. Otherwise, consider removing it since a future release of Flutter will remove these deprecated APIs.
If you are plugin author, take a look at the docs for migrating the plugin to the V2 embedding: https://flutter.dev/go/android-plugin-migration.
Launching lib\main.dart on Android SDK built for x86 in debug mode...

FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.
* Where:
Build file 'C:\Users\emiry\Desktop\Simto-To-Do-List\simto_todolist\android\build.gradle' line: 28

* What went wrong:
A problem occurred evaluating root project 'android'.
> Project with path ':app' could not be found in project ':firebase_auth'.

* Try:
Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace. Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output. Run with --scan to get full insights.
* Get more help at https://help.gradle.org
BU�LD FAILED in 1s
Exception: Gradle task assembleDebug failed with exit code 1
Exited (sigterm)
```

Answer (score 1):

Change your `minSdkVersion` to `23`

OR

Add this in app->android->settings.gradle

```
def flutterProjectRoot = rootProject.projectDir.parentFile.toPath()

def plugins = new Properties()
def pluginsFile = new File(flutterProjectRoot.toFile(), '.flutter-plugins')
if (pluginsFile.exists()) {
    pluginsFile.withReader('UTF-8') { reader -> plugins.load(reader) }
}

plugins.each { name, path ->
    def pluginDirectory = flutterProjectRoot.resolve(path).resolve('android').toFile()
    include ":$name"
    project(":$name").projectDir = pluginDirectory
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the response. I got an error after doing what you said. I added it to the topic.

Comment: Add this line in app -> build.gradle:   android {

    defaultConfig {
        ...
        multiDexEnabled true
    }
    ...
}

dependencies {
  implementation 'androidx.multidex:multidex:2.0.1'
}

Comment: Unfortunately I got an error again. I added it to the topic. Thanks for the help.